# SQLite_Busy during Transaction in Java?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, transactions

I have a CSV file with more than 10000 records, each of them long about 1000 chars to add to a sqlite Database.

Doing this, it works, but it's very slow:

```
try{

    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
       preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("BEGIN");
       preparedStatement.execute();


        //All prepared statements with inserts and selects

       preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("COMMIT");
       preparedStatement.execute();

    }
}catch(SQLException){

    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("ROLLBACK");
    preparedStatement.execute();
}
```

To speed up it, I want to do only one transaction and so i changed it to:

```
try{
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("BEGIN");
    preparedStatement.execute();

    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        //All prepared statements
    }
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("COMMIT");
    preparedStatement.execute();

}catch(SQLException){
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("ROLLBACK");
    preparedStatement.execute();
}
```

But i get this exception after about 1000 insert:

> org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)

What is it? I'm pretty sure that it's the only one task that is using the DB. How can i solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of sending `BEGIN`, `COMMIT`, etc. you might have better luck using `connection.setAutoCommit(false)`, `preparedStatement.addBatch()`, `preparedStatement.executeBatch()`, and `connection.commit()`.

Comment: I'm going to try it, thanks!

Comment: Nothing is changed. Still looking a solution